# stiff set wings

Tags: meaning, adjectives

> In the dark the old man could feel the morning coming and as he rowed he heard the trembling sound as flying fish left the water and the housing that their **stiff set wings** made as they soared away in the darkness.

*From "The old man and the sea" by Ernest Hemingway*

**Stiff** and **set** are two different adjectives describing the **wings**, right? But I don't get the meaning of **set** here.

Comment: "set" could mean "fixed in position, rigid"

Comment: The fins ('wings') of flying fish do not flap in the way that true wings do. They enable the fish to glide. Forward propulsion can only take place in water.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I watched a video on youtube to help me get a better view. Thanks for your clear explanations

Comment: When I wrote 'true wings' I think I meant 'birds' wings'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set** is a tough word because it has so many meanings!  Yes, **stiff** and **set** both describe the wings.  [The meaning of **set** here is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set)

> 23a : to fix firmly : make immobile : give rigid form or condition to

Comment: So you mean **set** is used in its past participle form, right?

Comment: @MostafaF.Rad  In the definition I used, yes, it would be a past participle.  But you could also interpret it as an adjective, like **5a: IMMOVABLE, RIGID**.  The meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say ***stiff*** adverbially modifies ***set*** in OP's context, but that may be just a matter of opinion. Compare these two written instances...

> 1: [*the bird goes gaily on, and with **stiff-set wings** sails downward*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with%20stiff%20set%20wings%22)
> 2: [*A strong-framed man of thirty-nine with **hard-set good looks***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with%20hard%20set%20good%22)

...where in both cases it's worth noting the ***hyphen*** joining the two adjectival terms - which to me implies that the first adjective more closely associates with the immediately-following *second* adjective than with the actual noun. In my book, an adjective that modifies another adjective is more properly called an ***adverb*** (even though it doesn't *actually* modify a ***verb***, as the name might suggest).

In context, the word ***set*** carries very little meaning over and above that conveyed by ***stiff*** anyway, but essentially it refers to the *physical arrangement*, the *way* the bird is holding its wings. Compare to the ***setting*** of a diamond in a wedding ring, or [*I liked the **set** of his shoulders*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22liked%20the%20set%20of%20his%20shoulders%22) (the confident ***way*** he held his shoulders; he didn't slouch).

Comment: What do you mean by "OP's context"? And what does *OP* stand for?

Comment: @MostafaF.Rad - the OP is the Original Poster (you).